# Cannot create new user in sql server 2000 with same name as deleted username

Tags: sql-server

We had to delete an old username from all our databases, however now when we try to add it back we are getting Error 15023 user already exists. I have checked all the databases to make sure that it does not and I have run

```
EXEC sp_change_users_login 'Auto_Fix', 'my_example_username'
```

However this fixed 0 and I am still getting the same error. I also tried putting the domain in front of my_example_username when running auto_fix, but still no luck.

I create the user in the enterprise manager by going to logins and adding a new user.

I am running windows server 2000, iis 6 and sql server 2003.

Comment: There's no such thing as SQLServer 2003 to the berst of my knowledge.

Comment: Did you verify the user doesn't exist in Enterprise Manager -> Security -> Logins? Or did you just use Enterprise Manager and check each database -> Security -> Users? The former may need to be checked since that is where logins to SQL Server are stored. The latter is just the user mappings assigned to each database.

Comment: Try EXEC sp_change_users_login 'Report' to get all the username and see if the user name exits or not?

Comment: @ShanPlourde I checked both the logins and users

Answer (score 1):

Please try this on your DB:-

```
   EXEC sp_change_users_login 'Auto_Fix', 'my_example_username', NULL, 'Password'
```

Check out this [link](http://www.experts-exchange.com/Microsoft/Development/MS-SQL-Server/SQL_Server_2008/A_4376-SQL-Server-Error-%2715023%27-User-or-role-already-exists-in-the-current-database-when-you-perform-restore-database-from-backup.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try running

```
Select @@version
```

I think your version is 2005. I had the same problem with 2005...

It solve running

```
sp_change_users_login 'Auto_Fix', 'user'
```

or

```
    declare @user nvarchar(20)
set @user = N'user'

    declare @qry as nvarchar(1000)
set @qry = 
'
--Me dice si tiene algun schema y el nombre  de este
SELECT name FROM  sys.schemas WHERE principal_id = USER_ID(''' + @user + ''')
---se lo sacamos
ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON SCHEMA:: ' + @user + ' TO dbo

--si tiene owner se lo sacamos
EXEC sp_droprolemember N''db_owner'', N''' + @user + '''
----borramos  al usr 
DROP USER [' + @user + ']
'
print (@qry)        
exec (@qry)
```

I used dynamic sql because i had to delete more than one user..

Comment: double checked it is sql server 200